# HTML form target to top frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, target

I have got a home page with two frames created. (yes I know it's a fame and not an iFrame, I can't change anything about it at this stage and so I need solution for the question.)

```
<frameset rows="130pt,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" >
        <frame id="topframe" name="topframe" src="***.html" noresize marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" />
        <frame id="mainframe" name="mainframe" src="***.html" frameborder="0" />
    </frameset>
```

I have a JQuery code in the html file sitting in topframe.
I want to submit the form and get the result in the "mainframe"

I tried all possible things I could think of and also tried many solutions from internet but for some reason, result can be retrieved in new window instead.

I would like to get solution in jQuery or javascript to submit the form and get result in "mainframe" please.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Yes I am using jQuery but anything in javascript should work too.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```js
$(function(){
  var details="get values from your form";
  
  $('#mainframe').contents().find("your-div-to-display").html(details);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<frameset rows="130pt,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" >
        <frame id="topframe" name="topframe" src="***.html" noresize marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" />
        <frame id="mainframe" name="mainframe" src="***.html" frameborder="0" />
    </frameset>
```

Comment: ok, I have a <form> element inside the html file displayed in "topframe".

Now I want to submit that form but want the result displayed in "mainframe" replacing the source html file.

Comment: Just write that code in your topframe page and assigned the values to details variable.